# Is it possible to use a method of super() which is otherwise used implicitly?

Tags: python, class

I would like to override `dict` so that a modification of a key dumps the `dict` into a pickle right after being modified.

To do so, I overrode `__setitem__`. The code below:

- initalizes an empty "cache" (the dumped pickle) if it does not exist
- or loads its content if the cache exists
- modifies `__setitem__` to add the dumping

It works fine. I need, however, to account for the fact that `pickle.load()` also makes use of `__setitem__` when building the dict and should not attempt to dump it do disk at that time (as it is being actually loaded from disk). The solution I use looks horrible.

```
import pickle
import myconfig  # en extension of logging to format logs across my scripts via myconfig.log
import sys

class CachedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, db="cache.pickle", **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.db = db
        try:
            # load the axisting cache, if any
            with open(self.db, 'rb') as f:
                data = pickle.load(f)
            self.update(data)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            # failed to load the cache, create a new one
            myconfig.log.info("no cache {db} found, initializing".format(db=self.db))
            with open(self.db, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(self, f)
        else:
            myconfig.log.info("loading from {db} cached dict {self}".format(self=self, db=self.db))

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        # dump cache
        myconfig.log.debug("updating dict {self} with {key}, {value}".format(self=self, key=key, value=value))
        # do not write the cache when called from __init__: we are populating the dict
        if sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name != '__init__':
            try:
                with open(self.db, 'wb') as f:
                    pickle.dump(self, f)
            except Exception as e:
                myconfig.log.error("cannot update cache: {e}".format(e=e))


a = CachedDict("hello.pickle")
a['hello'] = 'world'
a[3] = 5
a['hello'] = 'wazaa'
myconfig.log.debug("final dict: {a}".format(a=a))
```

This outputs

```
2016-01-11 12:59:54,134 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 25 | __setitem__ | updating dict {3: 5} with 3, 5
2016-01-11 12:59:54,134 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 25 | __setitem__ | updating dict {3: 5, 'hello': 'wazaa'} with hello, wazaa
2016-01-11 12:59:54,136 | INFO | scratch_48 | 20 | __init__ | loading from hello.pickle cached dict {3: 5, 'hello': 'wazaa'}
2016-01-11 12:59:54,136 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 25 | __setitem__ | updating dict {3: 5, 'hello': 'world'} with hello, world
2016-01-11 12:59:54,137 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 25 | __setitem__ | updating dict {3: 5, 'hello': 'world'} with 3, 5
2016-01-11 12:59:54,138 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 25 | __setitem__ | updating dict {3: 5, 'hello': 'wazaa'} with hello, wazaa
2016-01-11 12:59:54,139 | DEBUG | scratch_48 | 39 | <module> | final dict: {3: 5, 'hello': 'wazaa'}
```

The problem is at the line

```
data = pickle.load(f)
```

Is there a way to instruct Python to use the `super()` version of `__setitem__` for that single case?

Comment: Have you thought about making a decorator for your case? then you could just wrap any function or method call with it.

Answer (score 0):

you write the data into file imediately after dict is updated and close file, 
how to you prevent this CachedDict may be called with multiple threads or may be modify by user in the interval of two call of pickle.dump?

Can you just wrap a normal dict in CachedDict,  then dump and close the file when calling cachedDict.close  explicitly (or in _del__)?

Comment: The locking is handled in the code - I gave a bare example to scale down to the problem itself. I am aware of race conditions for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

how about this,I think Delegation is better than Inheritance

```
class CachedDict():
    def __store(self):
        try:
            with open(self.db, 'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(self.__dict, f)
        except Exception as e:
            print  "cannot update cache: {e}".format(e=e)
    def __init__(self, db="cache.pickle", **kwargs):
        self.__dict = {}
        self.db = db
        try:
            # load the axisting cache, if any
            with open(self.db, 'rb') as f:
                data = pickle.load(f)
            self.update(data)
        except:
            self.__store()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict[key] = value
        self.__store()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__dict.__str__()
```